# Trade history report from Bitfinex API

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin, trading, ccxt

I'm using Bitfinex's WebSockets API v2 via their  [Node.JS package](https://github.com/bitfinexcom/bitfinex-api-node). I'm able to connect and get a snapshot of my wallets. I would also like to get a report on my trade history (which is accessible on the website through *Reports > Trade History*), but I have not been able to get this through the API.

For example, after authenticating as follows...

```
const BFX = require('bitfinex-api-node')

const bitfinexClient = new BFX(API_KEY, API_SECRET, {
  version: 2,
  transform: true
}).ws

bitfinexClient.on('open', () => {
  bws .auth()
})
```

...the following code,  delivers me a snapshot of my wallets:

```
bitfinexClient.on('auth', () => {
  bitfinexClient.on('ws', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
})

// Result:
// [ [ 'funding', 'ETH', 123456789, 0, null ],
//   [ 'funding', 'IOT', 123456789, 0, null ],
//   [ 'exchange', 'LTC', 123456789, 0, null ],
// etc.
```

...while the following delivers nothing:

```
bitfinexClient.on('auth', () => {
  bitfinexClient.on('te', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

I have tried subscribing to the `'trade'`, `'te'`, `'tu'`, `'os'`, and `'hos'` events, but I don't seem to be getting any of them.

I have also tried using [ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt). ccxt has `fetchMyTrades()` and `fetchMyOrders()` functions, which should give me the data I need. However, for both v1 and v2 of the API, they return an error saying that `fetchMyTrades`/`fetchMyOrders` is `not supported yet`.

**Is there really currently no way to get a trade history report from the Bitfinex API?** If there is, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

You can still fetch your private trades from Bitfinex v1 with CCXT, like so:

```
"use strict";

const ccxt = require ('ccxt')

const exchange = new ccxt.bitfinex ({
    'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY', // ←---- change your credentials
    'secret': 'YOUR_SECRET',
});

(async () => {
    await exchange.loadMarkets ()
    const myTrades = await exchange.private_post_mytrades ({
        'symbol': exchange.markets['BTC/USD'].id, // ←-- choose your pair
        'timestamp': exchange.seconds () - 86400 * 365, // ← last 365 days
    })
    console.log (myTrades)
}) ()
```

More about it here:

- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#api-methods--endpoints
- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#passing-parameters-to-api-methods

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I have many accounts, and when I try to iterate over them I often run into the 60 requests per minute limit. I would like to make one request which will give me all of my trade history.

Comment: You can set timestamp to 0 or 1 if you want the full history from the beginning of time. If you receive less trades it means Bitfinex is limiting the output, in that case you will have to iterate.

Comment: I meant that I have to iterate over trading pairs (BTCUSD, LTCUSD, ETHUSD, IOTBTC, etc.)

Comment: Sure you do have to iterate over pairs, no exchange will output all history to you at once, otherwise they could've been attacked very easily. From my own experience with more than 50 exchanges, including the Bitfinex, they will always limit their output (not the way you want it). So you will either have to adapt/adjust to their rules or abandon the exchange.

Comment: @IgorKroitor Actually, the Kraken allows to fetch the historical trades regardless of the pairs.

Comment: @Lubos, that's correct, thx! I wasn't clear, wanted to say that they will limit their output by all means. If not by symbol, then by limiting the time range or the trade count. In other words you have to iterate anyway. But you're right, Kraken allows that. And many other exchanges do. Not Bitfinex, though.

Comment: @IgorKroitor - unfortunately, the Bitfinex doesn't allow it. However, you can make it dynamic at least: 1. fetch the available trading pairs (there is get "symbols" endpoint), 2. iterate over each pair and fetch the trades history for it. This way you don't have to specify the trading pairs manually. If you put your Thread into sleep after each iteration (at least 2 secs), you will not be locked. The disadvantage: you have to wait some minutes for the method to finish.

Comment: @Marc sounds like you haven't read the Manual on how to load and cache markets and symbols and how to work with them properly: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#loading-markets...